# Why am I getting "npm WARN tarball tarball data for ... seems to be corrupted. Trying again." when using Node 18/NPM8?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a simple project that was installing fine on 17. I upgraded my node version to 18 and now I get these for all the deps when I run `npm i`...

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for node-notifier@https://registry.npmjs.org/node-notifier/-/node-notifier-8.0.2.tgz (sha512-oJP/9NAdd9+x2Q+rfphB2RJCHjod70RcRLjosiPMMu5gjIfwVnOUGq2nbTjTUbmy0DJ/tFIVT30+Qe3nzl4TJg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar zlib: incorrect data check
npm WARN tarball tarball data for handlebars@https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars/-/handlebars-4.7.7.tgz (sha512-aAcXm5OAfE/8IXkcZvCepKU3VzW1/39Fb5ZuqMtgI/hT8X2YgoMvBY5dLhq/cpOvw7Lk1nK/UF71aLG/ZnVYRA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar zlib: incorrect data check
npm WARN tarball tarball data for esbuild-darwin-64@https://registry.npmjs.org/esbuild-darwin-64/-/esbuild-darwin-64-0.13.14.tgz (sha512-YmOhRns6QBNSjpVdTahi/yZ8dscx9ai7a6OY6z5ACgOuQuaQ2Qk2qgJ0/siZ6LgD0gJFMV8UINFV5oky5TFNQQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
...
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID invalid base256 encoding
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID invalid base256 encoding
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_INVALID checksum failure
...

npm ERR! code Z_DATA_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -3
npm ERR! zlib: incorrect data check

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.../.npm/_logs/2021-11-19T16_22_54_385Z-debug.log
```

I have tried `npm cache clear --force` but that doesn't seem to help.

What is wrong and why are the deps marked as invalid?

```
node --version
v18.0.0-pre
```

**Other Steps**

1. I tried removing ~/.npm (I am on MacOs) but that didn't help
2. Deleted all node_modules and package-lock

Comment: We… haven’t released Node 18 yet - are you sure?

Comment: yup I compile from source and master is 18

Comment: I will try checking out 17.x and confirm that makes it run ok again then I can open a bug with the Node project. But I would rather leave the question open

Comment: Node 18 is still in the very early stages of development. Whatever the answer is, it will get outdated pretty quickly. If this seems to be a bug, I suggest moving the discussion to NodeJS team. Conversely, odd versions of NodeJS (such as NodeJS 17) are considered unstable. In the end, if you want to build a production-ready application, use the latest stable version, which is (at the moment) Node 16.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say you're own your own if you're using a prerelease version compiled from source.

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to downgrade to 16. I was using a personally compiled version of 17 before I pulled to 18. I tried rebuilding the 17.x branch but it kept having the same issue. I eventually had to downgrade all the way back to LTS (from site). I am going to try a 16.x build to see if that at least works. For now looks like all post 16 builds are now not working with a basic Node/NPM setup. Leaving question open until issue is resolved.